# The multi-part identifier ould not be bound

Tags: sql, inner-join

I'm trying to update **LICENCE** in **mydb.MATERIALS** table with **mydb_new.material** table by joining them on **MATERIALNO and MaterialID**. I have this query below, it looks correct to me but I get this error :

> The multi-part identifier "N.LICENCE" could not be bound.

```
UPDATE [mydb].[dbo].[MATERIALS]
 SET N.LICENCE= O.Licence
 FROM [mydb].[dbo].[MATERIALS] N 
 INNER JOIN [mydb_new].[dbo].[material] O 
 ON N.MATERIALNO = O.MaterialID
 WHERE N.LICENCE IS NOT NULL
```

Can you tell me how I can fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Try prefixing the aliases with `AS`: `[mydb].[dbo].[MATERIALS] AS N`

Comment: Do you use SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this **[`UPDATE syntax`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx)**:

```
UPDATE N
SET LICENCE= O.Licence
FROM [mydb].[dbo].[MATERIALS] N 
INNER JOIN [mydb_new].[dbo].[material] O 
   ON N.MATERIALNO = O.MaterialID
WHERE N.LICENCE IS NOT NULL
```

or:

```
UPDATE [mydb].[dbo].[MATERIALS]
SET LICENCE= O.Licence
FROM [mydb].[dbo].[MATERIALS] N 
INNER JOIN [mydb_new].[dbo].[material] O 
  ON N.MATERIALNO = O.MaterialID
WHERE N.LICENCE IS NOT NULL
```